# Override datatables css

Tags: css, datatable

I'm using datatables with their native css which saves an enormous amount of time.  What I want to do is override certain elements by my own css but preserve everything datatables provides.

Here is what I have tried but is not working, I'm sure there's something fundamental I'm missing here so feel free to point me to a turorial or something but I've searched the datatables forums and google for hours without success.

```
//Links to DataTables css and js 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju-1.11.4/jqc-1.12.4/dt-1.10.13/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju-1.11.4/jqc-1.12.4/dt-1.10.13/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

//This is my own css class
table.mycss tr.odd { background-color: red; }
table.mycss tr.even { background-color: green; }

//This is how the styles are applied to the table
echo "<table id='hof-table' class='dataTable display cell-border mycss' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by a difference in the level of detail the rules are declared at.

You defined `table.mycss tr.odd`, but if you search on the remote datatables stylesheet you can see that the first occurence of `tr.odd` appears in much more detaild rule (something like `table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd`) thus a higher priority is assigned to that rule.

Try to make your rule more specific or, if it's too hard, add the `!important` clause to your rule. This is not a recommended practice though, because makes future editing more complex, expecially if done by someone else.

You can take a look [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), it describes a pretty easy way of calculating the specificity of css rules.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was really useful background, will study it thoroughly.

In this case changing the css to apply to an id at the row level fixed the problem for now - although I might look for a more elegant solution depending on how much customisation I want to do..